# How do abstract methods work when there is no implementation?

Tags: java, abstract-class, abstract-methods

Based on this definitions i know what is an `abstract method` and an `abstract class`:

**abstract method**:

> An abstract method is a method that is declared without an
>   implementation

**abstract class**:

> An abstract class is a class that is declared abstract—it may or may
>   not include abstract methods

so, there are a lots of `abstract classes` and `abstract methods` in android

for example one of them is `ActionBar` class
and of its `abstract method` is `setSubtitle(int resId)`

Now, if you want set a subtitle for your activity do this:

```
getActionBar().setSubtitle(R.string.subtitle);
```

where `getActionBar` returns an ActionBar which has abstract methods. But how does it works when there is no implementation for `setSubtitle` method?

Comment: that has to do with how java works, it is not related to android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It "doesn't" work without an implementation; it is not possible to create an instance of an abstract class, which is a requirement for an abstract method.

The *actual object created* - which cannot be created from an abstract class, but is created from a concrete subtype thereof - therefore has an implementation which is invoked via [subtype polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)).

---

In this case `getActionbar` returns an object which has been created from a subtype of `ActionBar`. Inspecting the resulting action bar object - eg. viewing `getActionbar().getClass()` - will show what concrete type the returned object actually is. From the [Activity.getActionBar](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/app/Activity.java#Activity.getActionBar%28%29) method source this is expected to have a type of [`ActionBarImpl`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/com/android/internal/app/ActionBarImpl.java#ActionBarImpl).

Answer (score 2):

There is always an implementation, but it is just not defining the interface or abstract class your reference is a type of.

Instead there has to be a sub-class which implements or inherits an implementation for every method.